# I have a Block under my page and is pushing my page content up

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

I added a sidebar to my page and I am getting a block under my page which is fixed there and is pushing my content up. I am attaching a picture of it. When I try to inspect where it is coming from I get a `<shadow>` tag. I googled it and found that it's a Chrome DOM tag. But when I delete that the block still persists. Does anyone have any idea why it is formed in the first place and what I can do to remove it? Or is it a problem with my CSS??

Issue image

[image]

Comment: It's width and height 0, I don't think it's the problem. And if you delete it the problem persist. It should be a problem with your css

Comment: Probably something in your app creating shadow DOM elements. Hard to tell from just a screenshot though. https://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: none;` in that object within the css.

If that doesn't work make sure you refresh your cache and reset the browser so that a local version of the css is not save in the browser.

Hope this helps..